# AdMob Rewarded Ads: Can't link to store listing because app is not released yet. Can't test SSV flow if app is not linked

Tags: admob

We've tried everything, neck deep in documentation and gotten as far as we can (including getting test units to work), however we can't test on test *devices* — which we need to be able to test the full flow where a user watches a rewarded ad AND we get the SSV server-side callback (which works with test *devices*, but not test ad units).

As far as we can tell, this is likely related to the new "[App Readiness](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10564477?hl=en)" requirements to link to a published app — which we can't do because we haven't released yet.

So... this means we can't properly test all features and provide a quality user experience, especially since it will take time for Google to review the app and unlock our AdMob ads.

What if the fact that ads don't load, prevents us from passing app store review?

So let me ask you, how can we test a full user-facing ads flow before release, if we have to release before we can test? Surely they should allow test *devices* to work for this exact purpose?

Are they really expecting devs to release broken features, wait until AdMob reviews the app and unlocks ads, then test on test devices, potentially release an updated version of the app, all before we have a working rewarded ad-flow? Surely this can't be right!

We've tried contacting AdMob but they will only allow community posts. [No response for 8 days and counting](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/120596245/no-ad-fill-on-test-devices-despite-waiting-2-weeks-how-can-we-test?hl=en). We got a direct link to their contact form but we get errors when we try to use it, even after clearing cookies and the usual stuff. We tried contacting Google Play's (usually very helpful) support team but they said it's not their problem and sent us back to AdMob's broken contact form. We told them AdMob's contact form is broken and they said that's not their problem. What are we supposed to do?

Comment: rewarded test ads work https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads . Which programming language is used for your project? Use appropriate test id from above link and capture logs and update those in your question. Error log will tell you reason of failure ( if any ). If your test ads are displayed correctly then real ads will definitely work once your app is live

Comment: @AmodGokhale demo unit ids work fine but they don't produce the backend SSV callback. As we understand it, test *devices* should produce the backend SSV call, but when we use *our* ad unit on a test device, we get `error code 3: no ads to show`. Surely test devices should always be able to show test ads regardless of any ad limits in place, and without requiring us to be live on app stores. We're using C# in Unity.

Comment: is URL verifified on admob console? also try manual verification https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/ssv#manual_verification_of_rewarded_ssv

Comment: @AmodGokhale yes our SSV URL works, and has been tested with manual verification. However, this is not the same as properly testing the full flow in-game where the user watches the ad, our backend receives the SSV callback, and then the game recognises that backend has been updated, and updates the UI for the user.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that our app-ads.txt validation (previously validated with success) has disappeared since the new App Readiness changes came in. Our store presence URL is up to date in Play Console, and has not changed. Presumably because they now require a public app listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else facing issues like these, the solution was unfortunately just to wait.

With no communication or warning and no changes on our end, several weeks later our test devices started working, and our app-ads.txt status had showed up again.

Our best guess, as we had speculated, is that it was likely teething issues related to the new "App Readiness" changes.